# Counting Grades to print

Tags: python-3.x

Hopefully this will be very simple all I need help with is getting a count of the letter grades and then printing them along with the list. 
Here is my code:

```
def getScores(): 
    f_obj = open("scores.txt", "r") 
    data = f_obj.readlines()   #read file into a list of record strings 
    f_obj.close() 
    return data 

def displayData(data): 
    print("Name           Avg     Grade")#print headings 
    for record in data: 
        name, ex1, ex2, ex3 = record.split()
        exam1 = float(ex1)
        exam2 = float(ex2)
        exam3 = float(ex3)
        avg = round(exam1 + exam2 + exam3) / 3
        if avg >= 100:
            letterGrade = "A"
        elif avg >= 89:
            letterGrade = "B"
        elif avg >= 79:
            letterGrade = "C"
        elif avg >= 69:
            letterGrade = "D"
        elif avg >= 59:
            letterGrade = "F"
```

Just above here is where im stuck I cannot figure out how to do a count with the certain letter grades.

```
        print("%-10s   %5s   %5s" % (name, round(avg, 1), letterGrade))

        print()
        print(

def addStudent(): 
    name = input("Enter student name: ") 
    ex1 = int("Enter Exam 1 grade: ") 
    ex2 = int("Enter Exam 2 grade: ")
    ex3 = int("Enter Exam 3 grade: ")
    return name + "\t" + ex1 + "\t" + ex2 + "\t" + ex3 

def storeData(data): 
    f_obj = open("scores.txt", "w") 
    f_obj.writelines(data) 
    f_obj.close() 

def main(): 

    scoreData = getScores() # read data file into a list 

    while True: 
        print("""                    
          Program Options 
    1.) Display Students. 
    2.) Add a new student:  
    3.) Exit Program         """) 
        option = input("Enter option 1, 2, or 3: ") 

        if option == "1": 
            displayData(scoreData) 
        elif option == "2": 
            scoreData.append(addItem())  # add record string to our list 
        elif option == "3": 
            storeData(scoreData) 
            print("Good bye.") 
            break 
        else: 
            print("Not a valid entry.  Please enter 1, 2, or 3.") 

main()    # start the program
```

Comment: my problems have been answered and I have mended them thank you musical_coder!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you already know how to determine if a grade is an A, B, C, etc. So all you need to do is increment a counter at the same time.

For example, you'd add in something like this to count the number of A grades:

```
if avg >= 100:
    letterGrade = "A"
    numAs += 1
```

Then do the same thing for each other grade type. Since this appears to be homework, I'll let you figure out how to do all this. Most importantly, even though Python isn't strict about this, think about the correct place to declare the counter variables.

Once you've got that working, here's an "extra credit" assignment: see if you can do all that using just a single array.

Comment: thank you. I have written this code my self and hopefully you answered my question I'll go test it now.